# "…who/whom I can share my feelings with"

Tags: grammar

Is it a correct sentence:

> I just wanted a friend, who I can share my feelings with.
>   OR should I say
>   I just wanted a friend, with whom I can share my feelings.

Comment: Why we have at least one question per day, every day, about who vs whom. Do people never think to look at the archives before asking their question? There is a large search field on the top bar.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to understand the correct usage. Let's first look at the grammatical / linguistic use of it.

1. *Who* is used when referring to the subject of the sentence as seen in the example below:

*Who is going to the party tomorrow?*

2. *Whom* is used when referring to the object of a verb or preposition as seen in the example below:

*Whom should I discuss this matter with?*

Getting on to the trick to ensure correct usage

1. In the response, if you are able to replace it with he or she, the correct usage will be WHO. See the example below.

Q. *Who* was talking about poverty last night?
A. *She* was talking about it.

2. In the response, if you are able to replace it with him or her, the correct usage will be WHOM. See the example below.

Q. *Whom* are we going with for the party? 
A. We are going with *her*.